# Character movement speed changes with frame rate even when multiplying by delta time

Tags: unreal-engine4, unreal-blueprint

When I run my game in the Unreal Engine 4 viewport, it runs at around 100 to 120 fps and my character moves at the speed I want. When I select 'Standalone game' instead of the viewport, the game runs at around 380 to 450 fps, but the character moves a lot slower than it's supposed to. I've scaled the movement using delta time, so I expected the speed to be consistent at any frame rate, but I'm not sure where I've gone wrong. I've set up an axis mapping as shown below:

[image: Axis Mappings]

My calculations for character movement are as follows:

```
World Direction * ((Movement Speed * Axis Input Scale) * Delta Seconds)

E.g. At 100 FPS
1 * ((100 * 1) * (1 / 100)) = 1cm per frame * 100 fps = 100cm per second

E.g. At 400 FPS
1 * ((100 * 1) * (1 / 400)) = 0.25cm per frame * 400 fps = 100cm per second
```

Here is my character movement blueprint showing the example calculations above (this graph is in my character controller blueprint):

[image: Character Movement BluePrint]

The `UpdateCharacterMovement` event is called on `Event Tick`:

[image: Event Tick]

I added a print string to show the distance travelled in one second as shown below, but it shows `Travelled 100.x in 1.x seconds` at both 100 fps and 400 fps, despite there being a noticeable difference in movement speed. At 400 fps I'm unable to jump over a gap which I can clear easily at 100 fps.

[image: Print distance travelled in one second]

### Solution:

I didn't realise that the character movement component takes care of the calculations for movement speed and delta time etc when using the `Add Movement Input` function as pointed out by George in the comments. So I solved the problem by simplifying my custom event to the following:

[image: Solution]

Comment: The character movement component will multiply by dt again. Also, i'd use the component's settings to control speed, the add movement input function is really just expecting information about input.

Comment: @George Thank you. I didn't know that the character movement component takes care of all the calculations when using `Add Movement Input`. It's running at the correct speed independent of the frame rate now.